# regex: how to substitute a given character in a matched substring

Tags: regex

I want to replace a given character by another one but only in substring that match a certain pattern.

In particular, I want to replace the dash by underscore in all words that start with cmd_

ie: cmd_word1-word2-word3 should become cmd_word1_word2_word3. But a random w1-w2 elsewhere should keep the dash. And I do not know how many - there might be. Although there is probably a max of 4, if that helps.

I'm trying to do this with the Xcode search/replace function, but can also use vim, se, python, perl if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize the most difficult part I was trying to handle was to account for multiple "-" in a word.
But it turn out I don't need too, I just need to handle the case for 1 "-" and rerun the regex multiple times.

So in Xcode I did find/replace with:

find: cmd_(.*)-(.*)(
replace: cmd_$1_$2(

After the first run, the "cmd_word1-word2-word3" would have become "cmd_word1-word2_word3", and after a second run it would become "cmd_word1_word2_word3"